# What is the term for language lessons in which the native and the foreign language are spoken simultaneously?

Tags: terminologie, apprentissage

I recall a style of language learning where you listen to CDs in which your language and the foreign language are spoken simeltaneously. For example "Hello" is said in one earbud while "Bonjour" is said in the other earbud. What is this style of teaching called?

Comment: This question is not about the French Language as defined in the [Help Centre](http://french.stackexchange.com/help). It belongs to http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I reposted it there. Thanks

Comment: I guess you were looking for the name in English. If so, you can close this question.